# AngularJS ui-grid data value and display value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am looking at using the [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) team's new table / grid implementation [**ui-grid**](http://ui-grid.info/). It looks really great, promising and easy to use.

Tho I have a question / problem I can't find the answer to in the [documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial).

**I want a column to sort on a different value then the one displayed, how can I achieve that?**

I have a `rank` property ranging from `1` to `10` which I want to sort on but I have a `rank_name` property I want to be displayed.

The `rank` property would be the `data value` and the `rank_name` would be the `display value` for the column.

```
var members = [
    {
        name: 'Member 1',
        rank: 1,
        rank_name: 'Grand Admiral'
    },
    {
        name: 'Member 2',
        rank: 2,
        rank_name: 'Aspirant'
    }
]
```

Take the following list of members as an example, the `rank` property should not be its own column but be hidden, the `rank_name` should be visible as its own column.

But if you try and sort members from highest rank to lowest rank it would sort it alphabetically and not by the rank number which is the real rank indicator. Thus placing the `Aspirant` at the top and not the `Grand Admiral`.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs: [
        {field: 'name'},
        {field: 'coords'},
        {field: 'rank_name', name: 'rank'},
        {field: 'score'},
        {field: 'strength'},
        {field: 'level'},
        {field: 'outposts'},
        {field: 'public_note'}
    ],
    data: members
};
```

Here is the grid options i currently use, but would like to add a sort value for the column definition for rank.

```
{display_field: 'rank_name', name: 'rank', value_field: 'rank'},
```

Comment: what do you mean by display value? are you using filter to convert data value to display value or something else im missing here?

Comment: @elaijuh added an example array, does that clarify it for you? :)

Comment: in that case, you might need to write your own sorting algorithm, checkout my answer :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below to `rank_name` columnDef

```
sort: {
    direction: uiGridConstants.ASC
},
sortingAlgorithm: function(a, b) {
    var rank = {
        'Grand Admiral': 1,
        'Aspirant': 2
    };

    if (rank[a] > rank[b]) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (rank[a] < rank[b]) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That seems like an excellent way to solve my problem, tho I think a simpler way should be implemented by the angular ui team in the future, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: actually in data you only need `rank` field (with number value), you don't need `rank_name`. just write a `cellFilter` to show string value in viewport but still sorting on number value. the pros of this is space saving for raw data

Comment: in case you don't know how to achieve this by `cellFilter`, i write another answer for you. good luck with ng-grid 3

Answer (score 3):

write `rankToString` filter in your angular module

```
module.filter('rankToString', function () {
    return function(input) {
        switch(input) {
        case 1:
            return 'Grand Admiral';
        case 2:
            return 'Aspirant';
        }
    };
}
```

columnDef for `rank`, you still sort on rank number but show the string value in viewport. so you can dump `rank_name` filed.

```
{
    field: 'rank',
    sort: {
        direction: uiGridConstants.ASC
    },
    cellFilter: 'rankToString'
}
```

Comment: The only problem to this solution, is it is separate from the actual data stored on the dataset... Would there be any way to use the filter supplying the information already in the cell?. 

In my case my data looks something like `{ name: 'date', data: { sort: '2015/10/02', display: '2 Oct 2015' } }`, so you get the issue here... 
I would need something like `sortingField: 'data.sort'`, much like DataTables behaves (in fact, I am porting my data API to use `ui-grid` instead). Is there anything similar that I overlooked in the docs?