# In angular-ui-grid, is it possible to sort a column by a value other than the column's display value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

This question is a close cousin to the SO question answered here: [Is it possible to bind the sorting of a column to a different property than its display property with Angular UI Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914459/is-it-possible-to-bind-the-sorting-of-a-column-to-a-different-property-than-its)

Our application has several "controlled vocabularies" that need to be sorted by an additional ordinal, not alphabetically, like so: "banana, orange, apple" and not "apple, banana, orange".

*This is how my question is different from the one linked above:* I do not want to have to add a second column just for the ordinal value, which is merely a number and should be hidden from the users. Is there a way to do this?

If I do have to add a column for the ordinal and bind it to the controlled vocabulary column to get it to sort (as in the linked question), can I at least hide the ordinal column and have it still sort as described?

We are not currently using Angular (this would be its foot in the door for greater things), so I'm hoping there is an obvious "Angular way" of doing this that a beginner can understand because after reading through the ui-grid tutorial this morning, I didn't see a direct way of accomplishing what we need.

Comment: May be a duplicate of this (which didn't show up in my original SO search probably because the title doesn't mention sorting): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678125/angularjs-ui-grid-data-value-and-display-value?rq=1 Can anyone familiar with angular-ui-grid confirm that this is still valid? If so, I think my question can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, it is still valid and this can be treated as a duplicate.

Comment: Wanted to add for potential future viewers that while the tutorial (http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial) was very helpful, the API for the gridOptions columnDefs (http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef) is more comprehensive (though often not specific) about your columnDef options.